# Porting ihooks to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m working on porting some very old piece of code to python 3.
I encountered a function that tries to use ihooks to load some other modules.

Thie code of interest is:

```
def _getCOMModuleForLocation(self, componentFile):
    fqn = componentFile.path
    mod = self.com_modules.get(fqn)
    if mod is not None:
        return mod
    import ihooks, sys
    base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fqn))[0]
    loader = ihooks.ModuleLoader()

    module_name_in_sys = "component:%s" % (base_name,)
    stuff = loader.find_module(base_name, [componentFile.parent.path])
    assert stuff is not None, "Couldnt find the module '%s'" % (base_name,)
    py_mod = loader.load_module( module_name_in_sys, stuff )

    # Make and remember the COM module.
    comps = FindCOMComponents(py_mod)
    mod = self.moduleFactory(comps)

    self.com_modules[fqn] = mod
    return mod
```

Could you please help me to make this piece of code compatible with python 3 while retaining backward compatibility with 2.6 and 2.7 ?

**Update**

Looks like I found how to make it work under 3.1+: [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html)

The question still remains for the 3.0 though.